# Creating an elaborate table

Tags: html, layout, html-table, cells

I am currently working on a new website and some issues are occurring while putting together a new table. As seen in the picture, the [table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ7mC.jpg) has a slightly more elaborate setup then normal tables. The issue I'm having is after I add a bunch of text into cell 2, cells 3 4 5 and 6 get pushed down below the bottom border of cell 2.

Here is the current code:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top" width="27%" colspan="3">
      <center><img src="IMAGE_URL" hspace="10"/><br/><a href="URL" title="TITLE" target="_blank"><img src="IMAGE_URL" onmouseover="this.src='IMAGE_URL'" onmouseout="this.src='IMAGE_URL'"/></a></center>
    </td>
    <td align="justify" style="vertical-align:top; line-height:20px" width="73%" rowspan="10">
      <font size="3">TEXT</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; line-height:20px; font-size:15pt;" colspan="3">
      <br/><center><b>TEXT</b></center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; line-height:20px" width="10px">
      <p align="right">TEXT<br/>TEXT<br/>TEXT</p>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; line-height:20px" width="10px">
      <p align="right">TEXT<br/>TEXT<br/>TEXT</p>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; line-height:20px" width="10px">
      <p align="left">TEXT<br/>TEXT<br/>TEXT</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write down the actual code because its fairly easy. What you need to do is this:

- Have a large table with one row and two columns (cells)
- In the first cell create a new table with three rows for the left side of your diagram (a row for "1", a row for "3" and another row for "4" "5" and "6")
- In the second cell of the main table content of "2"

That's it. Notice that the height of cell "1" will depend on the content you put in it. The rest will be fine I believe, and having the big main table will force cell "2" to have the same height as all the rest.

Comment: Wow, in all my years of coding I never knew you could embed a table inside another table, this helps out a lot. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @SamKarnack glad to help :)